# .NET Google Drive API Initialization

Tags: .net, google-api

i have an MVC solution and I want to allow users to save documents online on google drive.

As in other threads I followed the steps recommended in this link [Google API Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet), but when i can't execute the point 2:

> Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v3

When i write this on my console i have this:

```
> PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2
Tentativo di raccogliere informazioni sulle dipendenze per il pacchetto 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.14.0.564' rispetto al progetto 'CRMConciliazioni' con destinatari '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Tentativo di risolvere le dipendenze per il pacchetto 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.14.0.564' con DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Risoluzione di azioni per installare il pacchetto 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.14.0.564'
Azioni risolte per installare il pacchetto 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.14.0.564'
Pacchetto 'Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4' rimosso da 'packages.config'
Disinstallazione di 'Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4' da CRMConciliazioni completata
Aggiunta del pacchetto 'BouncyCastle.1.7.0' alla cartella 'C:\Users\Roberto\Source\Workspaces\TocTocTeamNew\ServizioConciliazioni\ServizioConciliazioni\packages'
Installazione non riuscita. Ripristino dello stato precedente in corso...
Il pacchetto 'BouncyCastle 1.7.0' non esiste nel progetto 'CRMConciliazioni'
Il pacchetto 'Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4' esiste già nella cartella 'C:\Users\Roberto\Source\Workspaces\TocTocTeamNew\ServizioConciliazioni\ServizioConciliazioni\packages'
Pacchetto 'Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4' aggiunto a 'packages.config'
Esecuzione del file di script 'C:\Users\Roberto\Source\Workspaces\TocTocTeamNew\ServizioConciliazioni\ServizioConciliazioni\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\tools\install.ps1'
Rimozione del pacchetto 'BouncyCastle 1.7.0' dalla cartella 'C:\Users\Roberto\Source\Workspaces\TocTocTeamNew\ServizioConciliazioni\ServizioConciliazioni\packages'
Pacchetto 'BouncyCastle 1.7.0' rimosso dalla cartella 'C:\Users\Roberto\Source\Workspaces\TocTocTeamNew\ServizioConciliazioni\ServizioConciliazioni\packages'
Install-Package : Formato del percorso non valido.
In riga:1 car:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I am sorry because is in italian but the error is:

> Invalid path format

I use .NET 4.5 and I have tried all the solutions, but I don't know what the problem is.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest version, which doesn't seem to depend on bouncy castle:

```
PM> install-package Google.Apis.Drive.v2 -v 1.20.0.711


Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.20.0.711' with respect to project 'WebApplication4', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Gathering dependency information took 20.68 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.20.0.711' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.20.0.711'
Resolved actions to install package 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.20.0.711'
Retrieving package 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2 1.20.0.711' from 'nuget.org'.
Adding package 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.20.0.711' to folder 'c:\users\rennie\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\packages'
Added package 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.20.0.711' to folder 'c:\users\rennie\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\packages'
Added package 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.1.20.0.711' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2 1.20.0.711' to WebApplication4
Executing nuget actions took 1.49 sec
Time Elapsed: 00:00:22.2747825
PM> get-package

Id                                  Versions                                 ProjectName                                                                              
--                                  --------                                 -----------                                                                              
Antlr                               {3.4.1.9004}                             WebApplication4                                                                          
bootstrap                           {3.0.0}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Google.Apis                         {1.20.0}                                 WebApplication4                                                                          
Google.Apis.Auth                    {1.20.0}                                 WebApplication4                                                                          
Google.Apis.Core                    {1.20.0}                                 WebApplication4                                                                          
Google.Apis.Drive.v2                {1.20.0.711}                             WebApplication4                                                                          
jQuery                              {1.10.2}                                 WebApplication4                                                                          
jQuery.Validation                   {1.11.1}                                 WebApplication4                                                                          
log4net                             {2.0.3}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc                {5.2.3}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor              {3.2.3}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization   {1.1.3}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages           {3.2.3}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotN... {1.0.0}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Val... {3.2.3}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Microsoft.Net.Compilers             {1.0.0}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure        {1.0.0.0}                                WebApplication4                                                                          
Modernizr                           {2.6.2}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Newtonsoft.Json                     {7.0.1}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Respond                             {1.2.0}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
WebGrease                           {1.5.2}                                  WebApplication4                                                                          
Zlib.Portable.Signed                {1.11.0}                                 WebApplication4
```